# get data from Ajax call other than string

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, grails

I want to receive some data from a grails action via jquery's ajax call.
Till now i have used ajax call just to receive some string but now i want to receive some lists(many lists) .
here is my action

```
def getSpecificData() {
        **some code here**
        render (list:[10,20,30,40],list2:[20,30,40]);
    }
```

My jquery call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: graphUrl,
                    data: "xaxis="+$(this).val(),
                    async: true,
                    success: function(response,textStatus){
                        console.log(response);

                     },
                    error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}
                });
```

The console log is `['list':[10, 20, 30, 40], 'list2':[20, 30, 40]]`
It is basically a string only but i want two list as response, is it possible?
I want those list1 and list2 as response data. Is there any way to do so?
I think i can make a json from lists(2 elements for two lists) and then convert json strings to array.

But that seem like mess so anyone have better idea?

Comment: What does your console show? Do you get the JSON you expected?

Comment: Are you trying to COMBINE the 2 lists into 1? Or ... your question is not clear

Comment: @nute a added the console log

Comment: XMLHttpRequests are limited to strings only, but jQuery will convert the received string into an object or array if the dataType and the correct headers are set. I'd be more worried about doing **Asynchronous** Javascript And XML synchronously !

Comment: @adeneo sound interesting. How can i put this in my situation?
Any help? thanks for taking interest anyway. and that async is false by mistake

Comment: Well, the point being that you can't really tranfer an array or object, it's all strings, and then jQuery does the conversion internally after guessing what the string really is, and it does that guessing based on the dataType and the received header, it's all very well explained in the documentation for $.ajax, and it's really no different from just calling JSON.parse on the returned string yourself.

Comment: Are you sure what you are seeing is not a json already? Try to continue your code assuming that "response" is a json object.

Comment: try to output to the console response.list and response.list2. If it works, then seems to me you are done.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/j-grails11188/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the server render a map with the lists as JSON:

```
render ([list:[10,20,30,40],list2:[20,30,40]] as JSON)
```

You may need to import the JSON converter:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
```

And then make your AJAX look like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: graphUrl,
                data: "xaxis="+$(this).val(),
                async: true,
                dataType: "",
                success: function(dataReceived,textStatus){
                    console.log('list:', dataReceived.list);
                    console.log('list2:', dataReceived.list2);
                 },
                error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}
            });
```

You may want to consider using the shorthand [jQuery.post(url, data, successCallback)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: thanks buddy that worked!! just curious do jQuery automatically determine returned data is string or json ?? i mean i dint write in dataType even it knows its a JSON how?

Comment: From jQuery documentation regarding dataType: The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response